# rpm -i says already installed, but rpm -e says not installed

Tags: centos, jmeter, rpm

I'm trying to test out an RPM I wrote for Jmeter on CentOS. I followed some guides online and when I do 'sudo rpm --install jmeter.i386.rpm' it says the package is already installed. However when I do 'sudo rpm --erase jmeter.i386.rpm' it says the package is not installed. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using `rpm --erase` correctly.

`--install` takes an RPM.

`--erase` takes a package name.

So `rpm -Uvh jmeter.i386.rpm` is paired with `rpm -e jmeter` or `jmeter.i386`.

As an aside, generally avoid using `-i`/`--install` in favor of `-U`/`--upgrade` as it has saner behavior in many cases (and will install a package that isn't already installed just fine). Alternatively, stop using `rpm` entirely and just start using `yum` instead `yum install jmeter.i386.rpm`. (Yes, `install` works for `localinstall`.)

yum takes RPMs or package names (that are in the configured repositories) for installation and takes package names for removal.

Comment: @ZeeshanPirzada Yup, happens to me all the time when I accidentally try to tab complete and have an rpm locally.

Answer (score 0):

in short words, rpm -i package_name.x86_64.rpm to install downloaded package.
to remove package, rpm -e package_name (without .x86_64.rpm).